# go http client and certificate authentication

Tags: go, https, tls1.2

We have a golang http.client sending a request every 5th second to a golang http server with mTLS (client certificate is verified towards CA on server-side), without creating client or transport at every request. The client certificate is valid for 5h and renewal starts after 4h. Renewal is always happening promptly after 4h.

What we observe is that the connection is established and kept open for the entire 5 hours, causing "certificate expired" after 5h in which the connection is closed and then re-created with the renewed client certificate. After that communication is fine for another 5h.

Behavior is not happening when setting client's http.Transport's DisableKeepAlives: true (meaning the renewal process in application is fine) but would like to avoid creating a new connection for every request. I.e. I'm looking for a behavior in which connections are re-established at a periodic interval, say every 20th second or when a certificate renewal is detected, even if connection is deemed "active".

Comment: Are you sure disabling TCP keep-alive fixes it? Did you try using the connection after the client certificate is expired? I would suspect the server breaks the connection on the first packet arriving after client cert is expired, which sounds like a feature rather than a bug.

Comment: @Cowboy: Without any example it's hard to say, but swapping out the entire `tls.Config` is _one_ way to do it. There is also [`Config.GetClientCertificate`](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Config), but like @rustyx mentioned, the behavior you describe seems suspect to begin with.

Comment: The certificates are properly rotated and picked up by the http client (through GetClientCertificate) whenever establishing a new connection. Problem is the persistent connection in which the SSL handshake is not done again.
DisableKeepAlives: true on the transport, in which a connection is used for one single request, makes problem go away. 100% verified.

Comment: If that's the case, did you try occasionally closing all the idle connections?

Comment: Thought about that too, but there is a (tiny) risk that connection is always currently active while invoking closing of idle connections. Essentially what I'm after is closing of ALL connections (idle closes right away and any currently active can close after ongoing request/response close), but I guess this behavior doesn't exist out-of-the-box.

Comment: I think if the server is going to break existing connections, then you are going to have to deal with retrying those occasional request failures.

Comment: I was more thinking that the client could reestablish all its connections (idle as well as active, even though active must complete ongoing request first) when it gets its client certificate renewed. But I guess similar issue could occur vice-versa with the server certificate expiry... hmm.
It just bugs me a bit that I can't find much info on this in general, i.e. how keep-alive (or persistent connections) behave with certificates with short validity. For now we will proceed with disabling keep-alive.
Thanks for input!